# What's the quickest way to install RDOCS for all my installed gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is there any one-liner commands that does this for me because bundle with rails doesn't install the Rdocs (how unthoughtful).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs -L 1 gem rdoc</strike>

That should do it. It will install RI and RDOC for each gem you have installed (and each version of said gems)

Edit: Apparently I missed the --all option that is now staring me in the face :).

So

```
gem rdoc --all
```

Thanks Patjoh

Comment: +1 because it looks right, but these incantations are never as readable by someone else.

Comment: No need for this. Just run `gem rdoc --all` for installing rdoc for all installed gems

Comment: @Patjoh I didn't know it took that parameter. Awesome :)

Comment: yay now my gem server isn't useless!